# How do Watched tags (with asterisks) work?

Tags: support, search, watched-tags

I follow `[*pokemon*]` as a tag. From my understanding, that will follow any tag that contains the word "pokemon" somewhere in it. This works correctly when I'm browsing the question list (they are properly highlighted), yet certain games with few questions, such as [pokemon-super-md](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-super-md) or [pokemon-explorers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-explorers), don't show up when I click on `[*pokemon*]`.

Why does this happen?

(P.S. I can't get the [tag:] formatting to work with the asterisks in this post.)

Comment: I think there's a maximum amount of tags returned when using wildcards (asterisks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, I was right.

## Wildcarding tags returns a maximum of 20 tags

Searching for `[*tag*]` is the same as favouriting `[*tag*]`, so I performed a few searches and compared the results.

This is what I searched. I wasn't particularly interested in the results, just in generating the maximum amount of tags possible:

- `[*pokemon*]`
- `[*sonic*]`
- `[*bor*]`
- `[*call*]`
- `[*sim*]`
- `[*the*]`
- `[*and*]`

When searching or favouriting wildcards, the wildcard is 'expanded' into the search box. Here are the resulting search strings from the above searches:

```
[pokemon-go] or [pokemon-x-y] or [pokemon-series] or [pokemon-sun-moon] or [pokemon-sixth-generation] or [pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire] or [pokemon-fifth-generation] or [pokemon-first-generation] or [pokemon-sword-shield] or [pokemon-fourth-generation] or [pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver] or [pokemon-third-generation] or [pokemon-bank] or [pokemon-second-generation] or [pokemon-seventh-generation] or [pokemon-lets-go] or [pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald] or [pokemon-black-2-white-2] or [pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum] or [pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green]

[sonic-mania] or [sonic-3-and-knuckles] or [sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing] or [sonic-the-hedgehog] or [sonic-3] or [sonic-the-hedgehog-series] or [mario-sonic-london-2012] or [sonic-and-knuckles] or [sonic-all-stars-racing-transformed] or [sonic-generations] or [sonic-the-hedgehog-2006] or [sonic-the-hedgehog-4-episode-1] or [team-sonic-racing] or [sonic-adventure-2-battle] or [sonic-cd] or [sonic-forces] or [sonic-generations-3ds] or [sonic-the-hedgehog-2] or [sonic-unleashed] or [sonic-rivals]

[borderlands-2] or [borderlands] or [bloodborne] or [skyrim-dragonborn] or [borderlands-pre-sequel] or [borderlands-3] or [borderlands-series] or [borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault] or [monster-hunter-world-iceborne] or [tales-from-the-borderlands] or [borderlands-goty-edition] or [borderlands-2-vr] or [battleborn] or [hello-neighbor] or [zombies-ate-my-neighbors] or [pvz-battle-for-neighborville] or [pokemon-reborn] or [harbormaster] or [final-fantasy-airborn-brigade] or [chaos-reborn]

[call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3] or [call-of-duty-black-ops] or [call-of-duty-black-ops-2] or [call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2] or [call-of-duty-ghosts] or [call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare] or [call-of-duty-black-ops-3] or [call-of-duty-advanced-warfare] or [call-of-duty-world-at-war] or [call-of-duty-series] or [call-of-duty-ww2] or [call-of-duty-infinite-warfare] or [call-of-duty-black-ops-4] or [call-of-duty-united-offensive] or [call-of-duty-elite] or [call-of-duty-modern-warfare] or [call-of-duty] or [call-of-juarez-gunslinger] or [theatrhythm-curtain-call] or [call-of-cthulhu-dcote]

[simcity-2013] or [sims-3] or [euro-truck-simulator-2] or [simcity-4] or [sims-4] or [pewdiepie-tuber-simulator] or [sims-2] or [simcity-buildit] or [american-truck-simulator] or [simpsons-tapped-out] or [goat-simulator] or [flight-simulator-x] or [the-sims] or [the-sims-freeplay] or [cultist-simulator] or [surgeon-simulator-2013] or [farming-simulator-2015] or [farming-simulator-2013] or [sims-medieval] or [artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator]

[the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim] or [grand-theft-auto-5] or [star-wars-the-old-republic] or [grand-theft-auto-online] or [the-witcher-3] or [minecraft-feed-the-beast] or [zelda-breath-of-the-wild] or [the-witcher-2] or [metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain] or [the-elder-scrolls-online] or [the-binding-of-isaac] or [the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth] or [saints-row-the-third] or [heroes-of-the-storm] or [the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion] or [the-secret-world] or [grand-theft-auto-4] or [grand-theft-auto-san-andreas] or [realm-of-the-mad-god] or [the-elder-scrolls-3-morrowind]

[minecraft-commands] or [borderlands-2] or [grand-theft-auto-5] or [grand-theft-auto-online] or [android] or [candy-box-2] or [borderlands] or [civilization-5-gods-and-kings] or [grand-theft-auto-4] or [might-and-magic-heroes-6] or [mount-and-blade-warband] or [dead-island] or [grand-theft-auto-san-andreas] or [mass-effect-andromeda] or [borderlands-pre-sequel] or [candy-box] or [candy-crush-saga] or [rock-band-3] or [skylanders] or [wasteland-2]
```

At first I thought it might be a character limit, but the search box actually has a lower text limit than what is returned when searching with wildcards. (try searching with a broad wildcard then delete a character or two and attempt to add another character. You can't do it).

Then I decided to count tags or more specifically, instances of the word `or` (including the spaces around it). Here's the results:

- 19
- 19
- 19
- 19
- 19
- 19
- 19

With 19 'or's, that means the wildcard functionality is limited to returning the first 20 tags it finds. i.e.

- `[tag-1] or [tag-2]` → 1 'or', 2 tags
- `[tag-1] or [tag-2] or [tag-3]` → 2 'or', 3 tags
- `[tag-1] or [tag-2]... or [tag-n]` → `n-1` 'or', `n` tags

Suffice to say, if you want to ensure all Pokemon tags are favourited, you might want to consider refining your wildcards, splitting them into 2 or more separate favourite groups.